# Combine inductive typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass, dependent-type

I have a permutation types with has a fixed sizes.  Now permutations form a group so I would like to make them an instance of a `Group` class.  `Semigroup` is easy enough:

```hs
instance
  ( Integral i
  )
    => Semigroup (Permutation n i)
  where
    (<>) = ...
```

However when I get to `Monoid` I'm a bit stuck.  I can't seem to make `mempty` polymorphic on `n`. For `(<>)` the type information of the size of the output was provided as a part of the input, but for `mempty` there is no input.

What I can do is define the class in terms of induction.

```hs
instance
  ( Integral i
  )
    => Monoid (Permutation Zr i)
  where
    mempty = ...

instance
  ( Integral i
  , Monoid (Permutation n i)
  )
    => Monoid (Permutation (Nx n) i)
  where
    mempty = ...
```

But this is not quite the same. For example if I do the following with `Semigroup`:

```hs
test ::
  ( Integral i
  )
    => Permutation n i -> Permutation n i -> Permutation n i
test =
  (<>)
```

It compiles just fine, but if I do the following with `Monoid`:

```
test ::
  ( Integral i
  )
    => Permutation n i
test =
  mempty
```

```
    • Could not deduce (Monoid (Permutation n i))
        arising from a use of ‘mempty’
      from the context: Integral i
        bound by the type signature for:
                   test :: forall i n. Integral i => Permutation n i
    • In the expression: mempty
      In an equation for ‘test’: test = mempty
    |
123 |   mempty
    |   ^^^^^^
```

Because we cannot infer that `Permutation n i` is always a `Monoid`. Even more troublesome is that if I try and take my `Monoid` instance and make a `Group` instance, I need to split that in two as well, since `Group (Permutation n i)` would require `Monoid (Permutation n i)` which cannot be inferred.

This is less than desirable.  I would like to just have 1 instance for `Monoid` and `Group`, just like I have for `Semigroup`.

Is there some way to define a single complete monoid instance?  It seems like there might be I just can't think of it.

---

The definition of permutation is just a wrapper around a type level vector:

```hs
newtype Permutation n a =
  Perm (Vector n a)

data Vector n a where
  EmptyVec :: Vector Zr a
  (:++) :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (Nx n) a
```

But really I'm interested in a general mechanism that would allow me to make a polymorphic object.

Comment: Can you provide an error message that goes with the problem you mention at the end? Also, could you provide the definition of `Permutation`?

Comment: Are you opposed to `data Permutation2 n i = Identity | MightBeIdentityButAlsoMightNot (Permutation n i)`? (You'd need to be a bit careful in making sure your API respects identities, with no typechecker support to guarantee it.)

Comment: @DavidYoung What error message?  There's no error involved here all the code works.  The definition of permutation should mostly be irrelevant.

Comment: I also wanted to see the definition of Permutation. The error message of interest is, I presume, the compiler error you get that causes you to conclude that "ghc cannot infer `Monoid (Permutation n i)`" (and the code you have to write to trigger that error message!).

Comment: You are exactly right, @amalloy. That is the kind of error message I'm interested in here.

Comment: It's really not interesting at all `No instance for (Monoid (Permutation n a)) arising from a use of ‘mempty’`.  It's exactly what should be expected since `Monoid` is inductive.

Comment: The problem is, I am able to make a full, working implementation of `mempty` and also successfully use it in examples using the code you've given so far. This tells me that the error you mention is actually likely important and likely to be related to a misunderstanding. Are you explicitly saying what type you want `mempty` to be (for example, using scoped type variables and either `-XTypeApplications` or an explicit type signature)? In short: The problem is not in the code you've given so far.

Comment: @DavidYoung I don't have any error.  The compiler is behaving exactly like I expect it to.  I need `mempty` to be fully polymorphic. My desired outcome is 1 `instance` of `Monoid` rather than 2.  Type applications can help at the call site, but I have no issues with the call site.

Comment: @WheatWizard Maybe there is a miscommunication. My concern is that I would not expect the compiler to have an issue here. Is it not possible to do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/roboguy13/349d3f7580eb11b8e69ab7ad766f7310)? Maybe this doesn't fit what you're looking for, and I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: @DavidYoung That's more or less what I have.  And it compiles.  My desire is to not have type class induction.  I want a single Monoid instance rather than a base instance and an inductive instance.  I've tried to edit my question to make this very explicit.

Comment: I think I understand now. Would you be okay with adding an additional constraint, like `SingI n`? It should be possible with that. All of the polymorphic recursion would occur in `SingI`, which would produce a singleton value. Without that, I don't think it's possible (until, maybe, Dependent Haskell is implemented in GHC)